# Ruby on Rails .find_by_sql quotes issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, find-by-sql

I am having an issue using the date variable in the following MySQL statement. The date variable contains a string which represents a date.

```
personal = Event.find_by_sql ["SELECT * 
                                 FROM events 
                                WHERE DATE(start) = ?
                                  AND HOUR(start) = ? 
                                  AND user_id = ?;", date, hour, user]
```

The following is the resulting query which is run on the database.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM events 
 WHERE DATE(start) = ''2015-02-27'' 
   AND HOUR(start) = 9 
   AND user_id = 123456789;
```

An extra set of quotes is added around the date string, which causes an error. Is there any way to get rid of the extra pair of quotes?

Comment: Note, the semi-colon is only required when entering queries in an interactive environment and they should be omitted when using a query interface like that. What value does `date` contain?

Comment: Does `date` have quotes in the string? `"'2015-02-27'"`

Comment: What type is the `start` column?

Comment: date does have quotes, because without them it is treated as a mathematical expression and results in 1986 being used in the SQL query. The start column is of type DateTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `where`?

```
personal = Event.where("DATE(start) = ?", date.to_date).
  where("HOUR(start) = ?", hour).
  where(user_id: user)
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it returns the exact same results.

Comment: Even if you parse `date` to a Date first, using `to_date`?

Comment: Yes sorry that does fix the problem of having an extra pair of quotes, however, I only want to compare the date part of the datetime column, this was the reason for using WHERE DATE(start) = ?.

Comment: Of course, that was a silly oversight. Does the edited version work for you?